# React Native: can't call a parent method from child

Tags: react-native

I have this function in parent component, and I am trying to call this method/function in child , like so:

```
buttonPressed = () => {
  console.log('button pressed')
}

<childComp ref={ref => this.feedback = ref}
           onPress={this.buttonPressed}
/>
```

in child:

```
<Animated.View>
  ...   // other views
  <View>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.buttonPressed}> // calling here
     ...
    </TouchableOpacity>

  </View>
</Animated.View>
```

No matter what I tried , it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are passing onPress prop to child and calling buttonPressed in child. it should be like this :

```js
<Animated.View>
  ...   // other views
  <View>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.onPress}> // calling here
     ...
    </TouchableOpacity>

  </View>
</Animated.View>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that in child component you should call to `this.props.onPress()`, because the name of the property thar you are passing is `onPress`. Also, don't forget to put `()` when you want to call the function. So it should be:

```
<Animated.View>
  ...   // other views
  <View>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.onPress()}> // calling here
     ...
    </TouchableOpacity>

  </View>
</Animated.View>
```